# What is the use of dual differential amplifiers in audio applications?

Tags: audio, input, differential

**Why do audio amplifiers use dual differential pairs sometimes?**

Is there a mathematical justification and not just "the joy of symmetry"?
Any hints, especially with some math would be of great help.

Example of an input stage constructed this way.

[image]

From: http://users.ece.gatech.edu/mleach/lowtim/instage.html

Comment: Posting an image of at least one example would be useful - or provide a ink if your rep does not allow images

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well actually symmetry does play a very big role in why the designer would duplicate (And invert) the selection.

If we take just the top half consisting of the diff pair Q1, Q2 and the cascode load Q5 with the load resistors R11 and R13 you can see that range of operation will be further away from the upper rail due to the Vce drop through Q5.  However, we don't know the currents and values of the various R's so it possible the output pull closer to the lower rail too (but experience tells me not).

So a mirrored system using opposite polarity transistors allows the system to approach both the rails by the same amount.  Closer to one rail would be dominated by on polarity, closer to the other would be dominated by the other.  And indeed in some designs, this approach will allow you to actually drive *to* the rails.

But symmetry helps in others ways too.

Looking again at the upper stage only, you see that the output will likely also have asymmetrical rise fall slew rate capability.  R11 is what pulls the output high while Q5 is what pulls it low.  I'm willing to bet that Q5 will beat R11 even though no values are given.

The signals "To Second stage" will be complementary and will drive further circuitry (higher output current) to be ensure that the slew rate and thus gain bandwidth, distortion and other parameters are matched.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As you say, the ability of a circuit to sink and source current into the second stage my differ, dependent on which direction. But cant this be circumvented by using current mirrors in the differential stage? You can get identical sink/source properties. Furthermore by using a second stage that uses a constant current source you can get to V++ - Vsat and the other way around. So thats not a problem too, as far as I can see it.

Comment: There lots of ways to solve the problem, and yes you could change the diff pair loads to extract the differential currents, but then you have the problem of translating to the other rail to drive the complementary transistors.  You'd still have limited input range.  Regardless, the original question was with respect to the input diff pair and not subsequent stages.

Comment: Ok thanks, so is the only advantage the somewhat extended voltage swing? I wasn't able to find out if there was improvement of linearity as e.g. the diff pair has over a single transistor stage through the tanh-law. Is there some? Some hint on mathematics would be great. Thanks a lot.